# What's the formula to solve summation of logarithms?

Tags: summation, logarithms

I'm studying summation. Everything I know so far is that:

$\sum_{i=1}^n\ i = \frac{n(n+1)}{2}\ $

$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\ i^2 = \frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}{6}\ $

$\sum_{i=1}^{n}\ i^3 = \frac{n^2(n+1)^2}{4}\ $

Unfortunately, I can't find neither on my book nor on the internet what the result of:

$\sum_{i=1}^n\log i$.

$\sum_{i=1}^n\ln i$.

is.

Can you help me out?

Comment: What does adding logarithms help you calculate?

Comment: @User58220 For one example, a Riemann sum approximating $\int_0^1\ln(x)\,dx$ is $\frac{1}{n}\left(\sum_{i=1}^n\ln(i)\right)-\ln(n)$. Of course there are other ways to find that integral, but this could lead there too.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

By using the fact that $$\log a + \log b = \log ab $$ then

$$ \sum^n \log i = \log (n!) $$

$$ \sum^n \ln i = \ln (n!) $$

Comment: It might be noting that Stirling's approximation gives a nice asymptotic bound: log(n!) = n log n - n + O(log n).

Answer (score 13):

Since $\log(A)+\log(B)=\log(AB)$, then $\sum_{i=1}^n\log(i)=\log(n!)$. I'm not sure if this helps a lot since you have changed a summation of $n$ terms into a product of $n$ factors, but it's something.